# More forces at low energy?

Tags: particle-physics, forces

Just a quick question: In high energy experiments, the fundamental forces are thought to merge into a single force. My question is, in very low energy experiments (very low), do the forces we know about split up even more/is this possible or likely?

Thanks

Comment: As per 2013, there are only 4 known forces. If any experimental evidence showed up, there might be a fifth force. But there is no experimental evidence until the moment

Answer (score 1):

At very low energy one can consider effective forces such as Vanderwaals forces and induced dipole magnetic forces ("split off" from the electromagnetic force), or the nuclear force ("split off" from the strong interaction). "Very low energy" is basically the world you see around you through your own eyes, so I'm sure you can make up more examples yourself.

If you go *extremely* low energy (equivalent with cosmic distances), the only forces left are gravity and dark energy.